# EEUU vs EU: ¿Han cambiado las reglas de abreviación en los medios periodísticos?

Tags: plurales, abreviaturas, siglas

Las reglas de abreviación hasta donde sabía indican que una palabra en plural se abrevia con Doble Inicial.

Recursos Humanos: RRHH

Estados Unidos: EEUU

Como indicado en [Spanish abbreviation for the United States of America](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/706/spanish-abbreviation-for-the-united-states-of-america/708#708).

Sin embargo en varios medios periodísticos, al menos en sus ediciones electrónicas, cada vez observo más que hablan de EEUU como "EU".

Las reglas de abreviación han sido oficialmente relajadas ó ¿es simplemente una desgraciada moda en los medios debido a la ignorancia?

Ejemplos:

CNN: [La bandera de EU vuelve a ondear en su embajada en La Habana](http://mexico.cnn.com/mundo/2015/08/14/la-bandera-de-eu-vuelve-a-ondear-desde-el-malecon-de-la-habana)

Milenio: [EU extiende su vigilancia en internet](http://www.milenio.com/internacional/vigilancia_internet_eu-dominio_publico-dominio_privado_internet_0_575342528.html)

El Universal: [Descubre EU red de empresas de "El Chapo"](http://www.eluniversal.com.mx/articulo/periodismo-de-datos/2015/07/26/descubre-eu-red-de-empresas-de-el-chapo)

El Economista: [En inversión móvil, México va a la zaga de EU](http://eleconomista.com.mx/industrias/2015/08/09/inversion-movil-mexico-va-zaga-eu)

Alto Nivel: [Recuperación endeble de EU, un riesgo para México](http://www.altonivel.com.mx/55935-recuperacion-endeble-de-eu-un-riesgo-para-mexico.html)

Comment: Dudo poder reconocerlo a primera e incluso segunda lectura. Creo que lo leería más como una abreviatura de la Unión Europea, mal tecleada. Qué curioso.

Comment: Yo también tengo el problema que leo "European Union", pero es un problema irrelevante para el grueso de la población que no lee noticias en inglés y no está acostumbrado a ver "EU" como "European Union".

Comment: Terrible la evolución de nuestra lengua. Esperemos que la RAE cambie respecto a aceptar faltas populares...

Comment: A mi EU me lleva a European Union o simplemente Europa, lo mismo que US/USA me lleva a Estados Unidos de America.

Comment: Son los mexicanos los que escriben EU .... la gran mayoría (por no decir todos)

Comment: Son los mexicanos los que escriben EU .... la gran mayoría (por no decir todos)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Las reglas relativas a las abreviaturas no han cambiado.

Iba a responder en la línea en que apunta @guifa, asumiendo que quizás te estabas confundiendo con la UE, pero no, veo que **efectivamente se refieren a EE.UU.**

La única respuesta y explicación es que los medios de comunicación, **los "mass media", cada vez cuidan menos el lenguaje, y no sólo en EE.UU.**, al menos en España pasa lo mismo desde hace años y cada vez es peor (no sé decirte si es dejadez o que como cada vez cobran menos, les importa poco cometer ese tipo de errores).

**La RAE tampoco ayuda mucho cambiando ciertas reglas**, como cuando aceptó "cocreta" como "Forma coloquial" de decir croqueta, ya que **el mensaje que se lanza es "Tú dilo como quieras, que si sois muchos los que lo decís/escribís mal, lo terminaremos cambiando".**

In short: Dentro de algunos años, algunos leerán tu pregunta y puede que no la entiendan ;)

**En cualquier caso, bien apuntado y bien por poner los enlaces, se agradece**, a ver si alguno de los redactores de esos titulares, casualmente, ve algún día tu post y aprende a escribir, que para eso les pagan.

Comment: He leído ya varias veces eso de la *cocreta*. Sin embargo, al menos la edición en línea del DRAE no recoge la palabra. Por otro lado, eso de "decirlo mal" es opinable. El lenguaje evoluciona; hoy día decimos *murciélago* en lugar de *murciégalo* o *cocodrilo* en lugar de *crocodilo*, pese a que hace unos siglos se habrían considerado horribles incorrecciones según ese criterio, y no pasa nada.

Comment: Respecto a la "cocreta", sé que lo he visto en algún momento como "familiarmente aceptado", pero reconozco que no lo encuentro ahora mismo. Respecto a si "decirlo mal" es opinable, no lo es. Es muy sencillo: Si no lo recoge el diccionario está mal dicho. Si cuando lo recogía, hace unos siglos como tú sugieres, lo decías, pues estaba "bien dicho", así de simple. Y en cuanto a que el lenguaje evolucione, totalmente de acuerdo, pero si "evoluciona" porque cierta gente no sabe pronunciar o escribir un término, resulta algo decepcionante.

Comment: Sobre si algún redactor lee esta pregunta y le da por aprender algo, quien sabe. Ya he dejado mensajes sobre ese detalle en los comentarios de CNN y Milenio me parece. Realmente dudo que les importe, y cada vez es más extendido y común. (Los de más lo hacen? Pues yo también.)

Comment: Desde luego si nadie lo comenta es seguro que no les va a importar, pero si has dejado algún comentario en sus plataformas ya es menos probable que no se entere al menos alguno de ellos antes o después, así que como hispano-hablante vuelvo a agradecerte el tiempo empleado; seguro que no cae en saco roto.

Comment: @AlbertoMartín: humildemente disiento de que "si está en el diccionario está bien dicho". Por mucho que lo incluya el DRAE me parece una aberración "güisqui", "cederrón" y similares.

Answer (score 4):

No sé si será influencia de «US», que omite el «America».

Y no sé si se han dado cuenta de que muchos vamos a traducirlo mentalmente como "European Union".

Hasta donde yo sé, los Estados Unidos siguen abreviándose como [EE. UU. o EUA](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/ee-uu-eua-usa-us/).

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo en mi caso, soy chileno. "EU" sería difícil de entender en una primera lectura, como dice @guifa.

Comment: No creo, la abreviación de US/USA es mucha más antigua que esta moda que tiene como año y medio (desde que me dí cuenta).
Yo también tengo el problema que leo "European Union", pero es un problema irrelevante para el grueso de la población que no lee noticias en inglés

Comment: Creo que más que de un cambio de regla se trata de economía de caracteres, similar a la omisión del punto en las abreviaturas en titulares, encabezados y marquesinas.

Answer (score 3):

Desgraciadamente, yo observo que esa es una falta de ortografía que se da principalmente en los medios mexicanos y ha ocurrido desde hace ya muchos años. El primero que vi que cometía esa burrada era el diario El Norte, de Monterrey, que nunca se ha caracterizado por ser cuidadoso con las formas gramaticales, aunque sí, por desgracia, por su enorme influencia en la región. Posteriormente, otros medios han seguido su nefasto ejemplo y ahora en México, las nuevas generaciones prácticamente no se acuerdan de esta regla gramatical -duplicar las primeras letras de las siglas de palabras escritas en plural-. Incluso, piensan que es incorrecto ponerlo así. Una pena.

Answer (score 1):

Según la [Real Academia](https://www.rae.es/dpd/Estados%20Unidos), la manera correcta de escribirlo es con puntos y con **un espacio de separación** entre los dos pares de letras: **EE. UU.**

Answer (score -2):

A mí me parece algo torpe utilizar cuatro letras cuando puedes usar 2. Creo que si pones "EU" y alguien piensa que querías poner "UE" por la Unión Europea es porque tu texto tiene muchos errores y lo más lógico es que el lector piense que es otro. Si tu texto está bien escrito, sabrán que te refieres al país yanqui.

Comment: Pero se trata de una seña semántica con información útil, permite diferenciar Recurso Humano de Recursos Humanos; Estado Soberano de Estados Soberanos, etc. Se suele abreviar esos primeros casos en contratos y términos de servicio cuando se usan como _comodines_ para referenciar a un sujeto.