# ¿Cuándo se duplican las letras iniciales en las abreviaturas? ¿Cómo se deben escribir?

Tags: ortografía, abreviaturas, siglas

[Una respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21904/1674) a mi pregunta [¿Cómo se escribe el plural de las siglas? ¿Es correcto escribir "ONGs"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21885/1674) indica que:

> Siempre había pensado que para el caso de siglas en plural se duplicaban las letras iniciales. Es el caso de BBDD (Bases de Datos) y RRHH (Recursos Humanos), por ejemplo.

Indagando un poco al respecto encontré una [explicación de Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/rr-hh-733/):

> Se trata de la regla para formar las abreviaturas de los nombres formados por dos palabras en plural: se duplican las letras iniciales, se escriben en mayúscula y van seguidas por el punto abreviativo y un espacio tipográfico: RR. HH.

Y me fijé en que esta duda se extiende a casos como [EEUU vs EU: ¿Han cambiado las reglas de abreviación en los medios periodísticos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13546/1674), por lo que toma valor lo descrito por Fundéu en [*siglas y abreviaturas, claves de escritura*](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/siglas-y-abreviaturas-claves-de-escritura/):

> en las abreviaturas con más de un elemento, tras el punto abreviativo se deja un espacio (se escribe EE. UU. y no EE.UU.);

y luego el *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* (DPD) en su artículo [*abreviaturas*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz) dice:

> En abreviaturas formadas por una sola letra, el plural se expresa duplicando esta: *ss.* por *siguientes*, *EE. UU.* por *Estados Unidos*.

Todo parece bastante ordenado, pero no observo un criterio oficial en cuanto a dos cosas que describe la primera referencia de Fundéu. Por tanto, me gustaría disponer de las referencias oficiales sobre lo siguiente:

- ¿Se utiliza este recurso solamente en nombres formados por **dos** palabras en plural?
- ¿Cómo se escribe cada bloque (¿tiene algún nombre?) en relación a los otros? El ejemplo del DPD muestra un espacio entre *EE.* y *UU.*, pero al parecer es algo que [cada periódico hace a su antojo](https://pendientedemigracion.ucm.es/info/especulo/cajetin/cc_oo.html).
- ¿Es válido decir *los EU* para hablar de *los Estados Unidos*? Es decir, ¿es obligatorio duplicar la letra?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cual es la pregunta ya que en los enlaces que has puesto está todo bastante claro.

Comment: @blonfu Fundéu habla de ello pero no encuentro referencias oficiales (léase _de la RAE vía DPD_). Edité para clarificar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La clave está en que no son lo mismo las **siglas** que las **abreviaturas**.

> [**abreviatura**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz). 1. Es la representación gráfica reducida de una palabra o grupo de palabras, obtenida por eliminación de algunas de las letras o sílabas de su escritura completa y que siempre se cierra con un punto.

Las abreviaturas son simplemente acortamientos de palabras. Pueden formarse con una letra ("u." por "unión") o con varias ("pte." por "pendiente").

EE. UU. es la manera de escribir Estados Unidos mediante abreviaturas. Como tales, van seguidas de un punto y se separan mediante espacio (aunque esto último no se suele respetar); y, por ser abreviaturas de unas palabras en plural, se duplican para indicarlo.
Si quisiéramos escribir el nombre oficial completo, Estados Unidos de América, escribiríamos EE. UU. de A.; donde América no es plural y por tanto no se duplica, aunque la abreviatura sigue refiriéndose a una pluralidad de estados. Se pueden intercalar artículos y determinantes, puesto que son abreviaturas de palabras individuales, no siglas.
Cuando leemos unas abreviaturas, lo normal es hacerlo expandiendo la palabra, es decir: escribimos EE. pero leemos "estados".

Por poner un ejemplo real de abreviatura duplicada de más de 2 palabras: cuando se habla de las Infantas de España, el tratamiento correcto es Sus Altezas Reales: tres palabras en plural cuya abreviatura es [SS. AA. RR.](http://www.armada.mde.es/ArmadaPortal/page/Portal/ArmadaEspannola/conocenos_noticias/prefLang_en/00_noticias--2010--07--NT-227-Entrega-de-despachos-ENM_es?_selectedNodeID=428029&_pageAction=selectItem) (de paso, podemos ver aquí un ejemplo de cómo el uso actual tiende a economizar los espacios entre abreviaturas).

> [**sigla**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nNmc4LzNaD6zHPhgWc). 1. Se llama sigla tanto a la palabra formada por las iniciales de los términos que integran una denominación compleja, como a cada una de esas letras iniciales. Las siglas se utilizan para referirse de forma abreviada a organismos, instituciones, empresas, objetos, sistemas, asociaciones, etc.

EUA son las siglas de Estados Unidos de América. Como siglas, se escriben juntas y en mayúscula. Da igual que la palabra sea singular o plural: se usa siempre la primera letra. Las siglas de Estados Unidos (sin el "de América") serían, efectivamente, EU; pero el uso de EE. UU. está tan extendido que poner EU crearía confusión (de ahí que las siglas reales sean EUA).
Las siglas forman una especie de palabra en sí; rara, pero palabra. Cuando la leemos, se pronuncia como palabra normal (si tiene suficientes vocales, como OTAN) o como letras sueltas (como FBI) o mezcla (como CD-ROM).
Las normas mencionadas en la otra pregunta para formar el plural, se refiere al plural de esta palabra completa, no al plural de las palabras que la componen (que ya hemos visto que es irrelevante).

Imaginemos que existiese el concepto de "Asociación Libre de Impuestos".

- Las siglas serían "ALI" (no ALII).
- La abreviatura podría ser "A. L. de II.", por ejemplo.

Si varias asociaciones se unen para formar una federación, diríamos que las ALI (no ALIs) del país se han unido para formar la Federación de Asociaciones Libres de Impuestos:

- Siglas FALI (no FAALLII).
- Abreviatura F. de AA. LL. de II. (por ejemplo).

Si hablamos de varias federaciones, serían las FALI (no FALIs ni FFALI ni FFAALLII), etc.

**Entonces ¿cuándo se duplican las letras iniciales?**

**Siempre**, cuando lo que escribimos es una **abreviatura de una palabra en plural**.
**Nunca**, cuando lo que escribimos son **siglas**.

Comment: Sobre lo de EU, según el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=estados+unidos)  las siglas son EUA ya que el nombre oficial es *Estados Unidos de América*.

Comment: Ahora leí tu respuesta. Gracias por ella. Creo que además es una muy buena respuesta a la pregunta _qué diferencia hay entre sigla y abreviatura_ jeje. La duda sobre en qué casos se duplican las letras iniciales (¿cuando son dos, como indica Fundéu?) sigue abierta. ¿Encontraste alguna referencia al respecto?

Comment: Lo que me pica la curiosidad es lo que decía Fundéu de: _Se trata de la regla para formar las abreviaturas de los nombres formados por **dos** palabras en plural_. Siguiendo tu razonamiento, ese límite de _dos_ no tendría sentido. De todos modos, intento imaginar un caso de abreviatura formada por tres bloques y no se me ocurre alguno. ¿Algún _XX. YY. ZZ._ en la sala?.

Comment: Me has convencido (aunque ellos escriben erróneamente _SS.AA.RR._, sin separar los bloques).

Comment: @fedorqui yo creía que eso estaba claro. Se ponen dos letras en los plurales de abreviaturas de una sola letra, como *pp.* para *páginas*, *vv.* para *versos*, etc. Los bloques que haya es irrelevante, no se especifica en ningún sitio cuantos puede haber.

Answer (score 4):

En [Ortografía de la lengua española](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi) podemos ver esta advertencia en el apartado que habla de los plurales en la abreviaturas:

[image]

#### Transcripción de la imagen:

> **Advertencia**
> Como puede verse en los ejemplos, el punto abreviativo debe aparecer detrás de cada bloque duplicado (*FF. AA.*)
> pero no detrás de cada letra (<sup>ⓧ</sup>*F.F.A.A.*). Tampoco es correcto
> prescindir, como se hace a veces, del espacio entre los bloques
> (<sup>ⓧ</sup>*FF.AA.*), ni de los puntos, dejando el espacio (<sup>ⓧ</sup>*FF AA*), y menos aún
> escribir todo el conjunto sin puntos ni espacio (<sup>ⓧ</sup>*FFAA*).

O sea que hay que escribirlo con punto y con espacio siempre.
A lo que llamas *bloques* también lo denomina así.
Todos los ejemplos que he visto con este recurso son de una palabra o dos, ninguno de más, ignoro si existirán.

Comment: Muy buen descubrimiento, gracias blonfu. Solamente me queda por resolver la parte de que se usa solamente cuando hay _dos_ palabras en plural. Busco y busco y nada encuentro :)

Comment: @walen Yo no he buscado en el DPD porque *fedorqui* comentaba en la pregunta que ahí no encontraba solución a sus dudas, por ejemplo si debía escribirse con puntos y espacio obligatoriamente. La verdad que si hay muchos recursos interesantes donde buscar :)