# ¿Por qué la "UN" no se escribe "ONNUU" en castellano?

Tags: ortografía, abreviaturas, siglas

"Estados Unidos" -> "EE. UU."
Según lo que aprendí del castellano y [unos recursos en Internet](https://es.quora.com/Por-qu%C3%A9-en-castellano-se-dice-EE-UU-en-lugar-de-EU-por-los-Estados-Unidos), cuando una palabra está en plural y se quiere escribir en siglas, sus iniciales se deben repetir.

Así, ¿por qué "La Organización de las Naciones Unidas" se dice "ONU" y no "ONNUU"? ¿Todas las palabras tienen que ser plural?

Comment: Como se ha indicado... la diferencia radica en que se lo lees con letras (sigla) o como si fuese escrito en palabras entras (abreviatura).  Solo son las abreviaturas que se duplican.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EE. UU. es una abreviatura, no son siglas. En la entrada sobre abreviaturas del [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz) explica este caso:

> En abreviaturas formadas por una sola letra, el plural se expresa
>   duplicando esta: ss. por siguientes, EE. UU. por Estados Unidos.

Cuando son siglas no se duplican las letras aunque sea plural.

En una pregunta en la que se trató este tema [¿Cuándo se duplican las letras iniciales en las abreviaturas? ¿Cómo se deben escribir?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21910/cu%C3%A1ndo-se-duplican-las-letras-iniciales-en-las-abreviaturas-c%C3%B3mo-se-deben-esc/21923#21923) no pudimos encontrar ejemplos en los que solo algunas de las palabras de la abreviatura fueran en plural aunque en teoría solo las palabra que son en plural se duplicarían.

Para completar la respuesta añado lo que dice @guifa en su comentario para saber como diferenciar siglas y abreviaturas:

Las siglas se leen como están escritas o si no es posible letra a letra (ONU se lee *onu*), las abreviaturas se leen como si la palabra estuviera completa (EE. UU. se lee *Estados Unidos*).

Comment: Entonces, Union Europea sería UUEE? No creo: se escribe UE.

Comment: UE son siglas no abreviatura y no es plural, así que no aplica esa norma en ningún caso

Comment: No entiendo como EE.UU es una "abreviatura" de Estados Unidos de América. Me parece un poco torcido.

Comment: Siglas y abrievaturas son dos métodos deferentes de representaciones acortadas de palabras, frases o expresiones. Siglas es un uso estricto de las iniciales de la alguna frase de interes.    http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nNmc4LzNaD6zHPhgWc A diferencia la abrievaturas son una forma acortada de alguna palabra o frase y usa un punto para indicar la abrievatura http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nNmc4LzNaD6zHPhgWc